# How to host website over public ip in centos 6 server

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, svn, http, hosting

I don't have router so i built the system as a router in CentOS 6.4 with the help of IPtables.

I have a server which is connected to the Local LAN. suppose 192.168.1.1

Then i forwarded the public ip suppose X.X.X.X, HTTP traffic over this local ip with the help of Linux Router using IPtables.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -d x.x.x.x -p tcp --dport 80 -j  DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:80
```

then i configured the Apache WebServer in my server.

in that i have multiple Virtual hosts. Like,

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@website.com
   DocumentRoot /path\to/directory
   ServerName www.website.ltd
   ServerAlias website.ltd
   ErrorLog /path\to/directory/error_log
   CustomLog /path\to/directory/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I use SVN for internal development

now i want that after development of whole day i want to show to client what is the progress done.

I have 3 public ip given by the ISP. one i used for the internal local LAN network.

Is it possible that i host that site over second public ip which is not in use

if Yes, then what procedure i have to follow.

If not then how i can i host that site over my used public ip.

for that can i just replace the my static Local server ip with the static public ip in virtual host.

I just want to show output to client which is i see on my browser locally.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to give your customer a public IP address and show them the site?

Comment: yes, i want to give the url to customer running over my public ip so customer can check the site which is under development in my office.